# Use CSS Modules in React components with Typescript built by webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-css-modules

I want to use the css-loader with the 'modules' option of webpack in a React application written in Typescript. [This example](https://github.com/css-modules/webpack-demo) was my starting point (they are using Babel, webpack and React).

webpack config

```
var webpack=require('webpack');
var path=require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin=require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports={
    entry: ['./src/main.tsx'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "target"),
        publicPath: "/assets/",
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true})
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.jsx', '.ts', '.js', '.tsx', '.css', '.less']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx$/,
                loader: 'react-hot!ts-loader'
            }, {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: "react-hot!babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }, {
                test: /\.css/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss-loader')
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css", {allChunks: true})
    ],
    postcss: function() {
        return [require("postcss-cssnext")()]
    }
}
```

This is a React component I want to style with an accompanying CSS file:

```
import React = require('react');
import styles = require('../../../css/tree.css')

class Tree extends React.Component<{}, TreeState> {
...

    render() {
        var components = this.state.components
        return (
            <div>
                <h3 className={styles.h3} >Components</h3>
                <div id="tree" className="list-group">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

    export = Tree
```

tree.css

```
.h3{
    color: red;
}
```

No matter what I'm doing (tried changing the import syntax, tried declaring the 'require' for ts-loader, described [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#loading-other-resources-and-code-splitting), I always get:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../../../css/tree.css"

at runtime and

> error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../css/tree.css'.

by the TS compiler. Whats happening? Seems to me that css-loader is not even emitting ICSS? Or is it ts-loader behaving wrong?

Comment: `import someName = require('/some/path')` is two different kinds of invalid ;-) - are you using `import` or `require`?

Comment: What do you mean? Thats valid Typescript syntax. @SeanVieira

Comment: Yea, TypeScript adopted sort of their own module syntax while ES6 modules were still being developed. It's a hybrid between CJS and ES6 where you use `import` (like ES6) but also `require` (like CJS). TypeScript also (now) supports full ES6 syntax though as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`import` has special meaning to TypeScript. It means that TypeScript will attempt to load and understand the thing being imported. The right way is to define `require` like you mentioned but then `var` instead of `import`:

```
var styles = require('../../../css/tree.css')`
```

Comment: Do I still need to define 'require' in a d.ts? Do I have to target ES6 in my tsconfig? I get the same error @James Brantly

Comment: You need to define `require` in a d.ts, yes, otherwise TypeScript will complain that there is no `require` function. The target doesn't matter, should work the same using any target. Do you still see specifically "TS2307"? If not, then it's no longer a TypeScript error and it's webpack saying that it can't find the file (due to a bad path).

Comment: Yes you are right, the TS2307 is gone. The runtime error comes from webpack. How do I need to understand the path? Is it relative to the webpack.config.js?

Comment: No, it's relative to the file that's doing the requiring.

Comment: Right... webpack just cant find the file. I tried pulling it into the same directory as the .tsx file. No luck... Do you have a working example of Typescript+rect+modules at hand?

Comment: There are a number of examples at https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/wiki/Tutorials-&-Examples but I don't know if anything of them deals with CSS specifically. When you moved it into the same directory, did you use `require('tree.css')` or `require('./tree.css')`? The `./` is important there.

Comment: I found the problem: The ExtractTextPlugin was obviously throwing away the tree.css and only emits style.css. Now everything works. Thank you very much!

Comment: but please use "let" instead of "var" in a typescript environment... ;)

Answer (score 9):

1. Declare 'require' as per [ts-loader documentation](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#loading-other-resources-and-code-splitting).
2. Use 'require' as generic with **< any >** type: **require< any >("../../../css/tree.css")**.

*.d.ts file

```
declare var require: {
   <T>(path: string): T;
   (paths: string[], callback: (...modules: any[]) => void): void;
   ensure: (paths: string[], callback: (require: <T>(path: string) => T) => void) => void;
};
```

*.tsx file with component

```
const styles = require<any>("../../../css/tree.css");
...
<h3 className={styles.h3}>Components</h3>
```

I know it was already answered, but I was struggling with it for a while before I realized I need to use generic type specification, without that I wasn't able to access content of CSS file. (I was getting error: *Property 'h3' does not exists on type '{}'.*)

Comment: Yeah or you can just leave away the generic <T> in the declaration of 'require': declare var require:{(path: string): T}

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/Quramy/typed-css-modules, which creates .d.ts files from CSS Modules .css files. Please see also https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/61#issuecomment-220684795

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. 
For me, works import:

```
import '../../../css/tree.css';
```

Webpack change this like any other normal imports. It change it to

```
__webpack_require__(id)
```

One drawback is that you lost control on style variable.

Comment: But I need the variable 'styles' for setting the className in the React component like: <div className={styles.style}/>
Can you explain further what you mean?

Comment: All styles are available as normal css. Then you could use it in your h3 component:
`<h3 className="h3" >Components</h3>`

Comment: I see what you mean, but my goal is to use CSS modules where every CSS file is scoped locally (one css file per react component). Thats why I need to assign the className programmatically

Comment: I see, I didn't find any better solution only this workaround. I will follow this question, maybe you will have a luck.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to game but you can create a file called tree.css.d.ts in the same folder as tree.css that has this line:

```
export const h3: string;
```

and still use the import statement `import * as styles from ...` and you will still getcode completion and compile time checking.

You can either manage these definition files manually or you could integrate typed-css-modules into your build pipeline (https://github.com/Quramy/typed-css-modules)